# Console chat server

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, socket, async-await, tcp

I'm just looking for feedback on correctness of my understanding of async/await. I'm curious about the `Task.Run` inside of the `StartReceive()` method.  Resharper (or maybe just the compiler) warns against doing this without an await, but I think in this case, it's ok.

After running, one can connect by telnetting to localhost 7776.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChatTutorial.ConsoleServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var server = new ChatServer();
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Listening....");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.PrintException(ex, "Main");
            }
        }
    }

    internal class ChatServer
    {
        private readonly TcpListener _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 7776);            
        private readonly Dictionary<string, LocalClient> _clients = new Dictionary<string, LocalClient>();

        public async void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                _listener.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
                        var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

                        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
                        var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        _clients.Add(id, new LocalClient(client, ReceivedMessage, ClientClosed, id));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Start() While() '{0}', '{1}'", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.PrintException(ex, "Start");
            }
        }

        public void ClientClosed(string id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} disconnected", id);
            var client = _clients[id];
            _clients.Remove(id);
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} Closed", id);
            ReceivedMessage("Client disconnected", id);
        }

        public void ReceivedMessage(string message, string id)
        {
            try
            {
                var clientsToRemove = new List<string>();
                foreach (var client in _clients)
                {
                    if (client.Value != null && client.Value.Client.Connected)
                    {
                        if (client.Key != id)
                            client.Value.Send(id + "> " + message);
                    }
                    else
                        clientsToRemove.Add(client.Key);
                }

                foreach (var client in clientsToRemove)
                    _clients.Remove(client);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.PrintException(ex, "ReceivedMessage");
            }
        }

        internal class LocalClient
        {
            private readonly TcpClient _client;
            public TcpClient Client { get { return _client; } }

            private readonly Action<string> _closedCallback;            
            private readonly Action<string,string> _recvCallback;

            private readonly StreamReader _reader;
            private readonly StreamWriter _writer;

            private readonly string _id;
            public string Id { get { return _id; } }            

            public LocalClient(TcpClient client, Action<string,string> recvCallback, Action<string> closedCallback, string id)
            {
                _closedCallback = closedCallback;
                try
                {
                    _client = client;
                    _recvCallback = recvCallback;
                    _id = id;

                    _reader = new StreamReader(_client.GetStream());
                    _writer = new StreamWriter(_client.GetStream()) {AutoFlush = true};

                    StartReceive();

                    Console.WriteLine("Local client {0} receiving...", id);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.PrintException(ex, "LocalClient");
                }
            }

            public async void StartReceive()
            {
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {                        
                        var message = await _reader.ReadLineAsync();

                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                        {
                            Task.Run(() => _closedCallback(_id));
                            return;
                        }

                        _recvCallback(message, _id);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} > {1}", _id, message);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.PrintException(ex, "StartReceive");
                }
            }

            public void Close()
            {
                if (_reader != null)
                    _reader.Dispose();           
            }

            public async void Send(string message)
            {
                try
                {                    
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) return;

                    await _writer.WriteLineAsync(message);                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.PrintException(ex, "Send");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Logger
    {
        public static void PrintException(Exception ex, string methodName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: \n '{1}' \n '{2}'", methodName, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is v3 is the final version of basic chat server? I would like to use it as my basis of scalable/robust client server application. Thanks.

Comment: It is.  If you really want the highest performance for a server, you'll have to use SocketAsyncEventArgs, which use IOCP (I/O Completion Port).  [C# SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod).  I believe Stephen Cleary or Stephen Toub has examples on using async/await in conjunction with SocketAsyncEventArgs.

Comment: What happens when multiple clients sends messages at the same time, wouldn't there be concurrent calls to Client.Send Method? Can the streamwriter handle that? Because I am having problem with that but i use the SSLstream.WriteAsync directly.

Answer (score 6):

As the latecomer to the party, I'll take it from V3...

First, `async void` should only be used for event handlers. I'd much rather see `Start` return a `Task` representing the listening loop.

For a simple example, you don't need to do any cleanup at all. Once your app exits, the OS will clean up after it. Doing cleanup just before application exit is just a waste of effort.

If you *do* want to cleanly stop an asynchronous system, you should be using `CancellationToken` - create a CTS in `Main` and then pass the token to `Start`. From there things get tricky, as many operations (such as `AcceptTcpClientAsync`) do not take a `CancellationToken`. There's an old trick in Windows programming where you can close the underlying handle (in this case, `Stop` the `TcpListener`) which will cause any outstanding asynchronous operations on that handle to complete with an error.

On a side note, it is almost impossible to shut down a socket *without* seeing exceptions; the general rule of thumb is that once you decide to shut down, just ignore all errors until it's done.

You can find out more about socket programming in my [TCP/IP .NET Sockets FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html). However, I highly recommend that you find another sample project to explore `async` and `await` (if you like to learn by example, there's a good tutorial built in to LINQPad). There is no such thing as a "simple" TCP/IP chat server. I've had many people ask me for sample `async` socket code, but I haven't given any out for a very simple reason: it's not as hard as it used to be, but it's still *really hard* to get right!

Comment: Appreciate the response! I fiddled with trying to clean-up cleanly for a while, it's good to know that that's the way it is.  Do you seen any issue's with the set it and forget it callback within a Task in StartReceive()?

Answer (score 4):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

If you're not using `args`, you can just remove them: `static void Main()`.

```
server.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Listening....");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Running a server until Enter is pressed like this might be okay in a testing application, but not in a production-quality one. Probably the biggest problem with this is that you don't give the worker thread any chance to complete the current operation or to perform cleanup.

To fix that, you could change your application into a Windows service. Or you could use a `CancellationToken` that's somehow triggered by the user's action and then wait for the whole `Task` to complete.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.PrintException(ex, "Main");
}
```

I don't see the point of this in your `Main()`. I can't think of any situation where this `catch` would be triggered.

Also, since you're using C# 5.0, you could use [caller information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) to avoid having to spell out the name of the current method.

```
new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 7776)
```

According to the documentation, you should use `IPAddress.Any` if you don't want to specify which IP address to use. That is equivalent to your code (`Any` returns 0.0.0.0), but I think using `Any` would make your code clearer.

```
public async void Start()
```

Normally, you should use `async void` methods only in event handlers and nowhere else. I guess it could be considered okay here (since you log all exceptions from this method), assuming you don't care about the cleanup problems I mentioned above.

```
public void ClientClosed(string id)
```

I don't see any reason to use just `id` here. Instead, the parameter of this method should be the `LocalClient` directly.

```
_clients.Remove(id);
```

This line could be run in parallel with other calls to `Remove()` or with the call to `Add()` in `Start()`, which means the code is not thread-safe. You should either use locking or use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of normal `Dictionary`.

```
foreach (var client in _clients)
{
    if (client.Value != null && client.Value.Client.Connected)
```

This is very confusing naming. Here, `client` is not any kind of client, it's a `KeyValuePair<LocalClient>`. And `client.Value.Client` is a `TcpClient`, which is not clear from the name at all. I would suggest you to rename `LocalClient` to something else. If you think that it's the best name you can come up with, use names to make the distinction between `LocalClient` and `TcpClient` clear.

---

There are probably other issues with the rest of the code, but this is where I stopped looking.